# How could it be that calling a free function from GLM (like dot) can compile without using its namespace?

Tags: c++, glm-math

Like in the following example:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main()
{
    glm::vec3 a;
    dot(a, a);
}
```

Without using the glm namespace anywhere, calling its dot function compile and works (altough it does not appears in the intellisense).

How can it be possible?

Comment: Do a Google search for argument dependent lookup

Comment: @RichardHodges Cool! Didn't know that was a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

During overload resolution associated namespaces are searched. This *argument-dependent look-up* (ADL). The namespaces associated with `a` in the call of `dot(a, a)` depend on how `glm::vec3` is defined. Assuming it is defined in `glm` (rather than namespace `glm` merely including a `using`-declaration or a `typedef` for a type defined elsewhere), names from `glm` are found. Additional namespaces may be searched if `vec3` inherits from class in other namespaces or is actually a class template instantiated with types defined in other namespaces.